# SQL query - How to find sum of salary of employees drawing greater than 10L and sum of salary of employees drawing less than 10L?

Tags: sql

I want output as below:

SAL_GREAT_10L SAL_LESS_10L
5000000000      6000000000

Comment: This is not a well formed question. It seems specific to a particular database.

Answer (score 0):

select sal, case when sal >100000 then sal_great_10L else SAL_LESS_10L end from table